# Error in Protobuf libraries compilation during installing Object Detection API Ubuntu

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection

I'm having error installing object detection api and tried to use below solution from this thread https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1570.

```sh
mkdir -p ~/installs/protoc_3.3.0
    cd ~/installs/protoc_3.3.0
    wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.3.0/protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip
    chmod 775 protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip
    unzip protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip
```

Then:

```sh
    cd ~/git/models/
    ~/installs/protoc_3.3.0/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
    python setup.py install --prefix=~
```

but I got the below error for the last line of code above.

```
python setup.py install --prefix=~
running install
Checking .pth file support in /home/ayshine/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
/home/ayshine/anaconda3/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /home/ayshine/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /home/ayshine/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations


Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Comment: It looks to me the problem was you were running commands from wrong directory. It should be: 

`cd ~/git/models/research/`
`~/installs/protoc_3.3.0/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`
You can try this and it should generate all the protocol files. I don't know what the third line does but the installation guide did not mention using it.

Comment: Thanks! I found the answer forgot the update this post. Turns out I didn't build protobuf and install it. Just downloaded and extracted.But version 3.4 of protobuf worked out for me though not the latest version. Your answer is also correct then I run this command from `~/git/models/research/``directory after installing protobuf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing protobuf described as on this blogpost solved my problem. 
https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/